# Add a new column to a dataframe from a Series or dictionary mapping my series index and a dataframe column to key pandas python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, series

I'm stuck with this problem, please help:

I have a dataframe and a Series as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [4,8,35,28,34,34,14,28], 
                    "cause of failure": [5,3,0,1,7,8,6,7], 
                    "crash": [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

And I have a Series:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'':["None","Design flaw","metal fatigue","Manufacturing flaw","Pilot 
                 error","Mechanical failure","Improper maintenance","Fire","Corrosion"]})
```

#To add the new column I wrote the add_column function, inside the function i convert  the s1 into #a dictionary but

```
def add_column(df,s, ref_column, new_column):
    dict_s = s.to_dict(orient='dict')
    #dict_s = s.loc[0:].to_dict(orient='index')
    error', 5: 'Mechanical failure', 6: 'Improper maintenance', 7: 'Fire', 8: 'Corrosion'}
    df[new_column] = df[ref_column].map(dict_s)
    return df

add_column(df1,s1,"failure code","failure")
```

#I don't want the empty header into the dictionary, just the key value pairs of the series

```
{'': {0: 'None', 1: 'Design flaw', 2: 'metal fatigue', 3: 'Manufacturing flaw', 4: 'Pilot error', 5: 'Mechanical failure', 6: 'Improper maintenance', 7: 'Fire', 8: 'Corrosion'}}

#Like this:
{0: 'None', 1: 'Design flaw', 2: 'metal fatigue', 3: 'Manufacturing flaw', 4: 'Pilot error', 5: 'Mechanical failure', 6: 'Improper maintenance', 7: 'Fire', 8: 'Corrosion'}
```

I cannot get the dictionary right

#Then I want to map this dictionary to match the codes in the column "failure code" and add those as a new column "failure"
Finally I want to add a new column failure to the df1 dataframe.

The result should be as the one below:

```
    ID  failure code    crash   failure
1   8   3   0   Manufacturing flaw
2   35  0   0   None
3   28  1   1   Design flaw
4   34  7   1   Fire
5   34  8   1   Corrosion
6   14  6   1   Improper maintenance
7   28  7   1   Fire
```

[Link to df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khnTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `s` is not a Series but, in fact, a DataFrame. use a Series in `map`:

```
df1['new_column'] = df1['cause of failure'].map(s[''])
```

output:

```
   ID  cause of failure  crash            new_column
0   4                 5      0    Mechanical failure
1   8                 3      0    Manufacturing flaw
2  35                 0      0                  None
3  28                 1      1           Design flaw
4  34                 7      1                  Fire
5  34                 8      1             Corrosion
6  14                 6      1  Improper maintenance
7  28                 7      1                  Fire
```

or building directly a Series:

```
s = pd.Series(["None","Design flaw","metal fatigue","Manufacturing flaw","Pilot error","Mechanical failure","Improper maintenance","Fire","Corrosion"])

df1['new_column'] = df1['cause of failure'].map(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! mozway. Yes, s it's actually a dataframe from a txt file, I've used:   df = pd.read_csv(r'frecuent_plane_failures.csv', header=0, index_col=False, sep=';') . Your solution works for my example but it doesn't work for my original problem, I get  ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().  If I use the df1['cause of failure'].map(s) or KeyError: '' if I use the df1['cause of failure'].map(s['']), don't know how to read a txt file into a Series. I can't build the Series because I must use the txt file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then please clarify your question with a reproducible example of the issue

Comment: I've converted the dataframe into a Series with:  s = df.T.iloc[0]  then I used map(s) as you suggested. Thank you, now it works!

Comment: @Sofia great, glad it worked, you might consider marking the question solved ;)